# How to loop through links and execute a jQuery javascript for each site in PhantomJS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, phantomjs

Im trying to build a responsive webdesign testing tool. I have managed to capture each link in an array of links in different device specific viewport sizes.

But an additonal requirement for the tool is to be able to inject custom javascripts into the site, wait for that script to finish and then capture the state of the page (For example someone wants to open a bootstrap modal before capturing it).

Ive been using the [jQueryGo](https://github.com/travist/jquery.go.js) Node Module to accomplish my work up till now.

### What I've accomplished so far

I've managed to make it work but without being able to use jQuery components(and ive tried using injectJs and includeJs provided by phantom). In the following code using asyncjs and some helper function.

```js
var $ = require('../node_modules/jquerygo/lib/jquery.go.js');
var async = require('../node_modules/jquerygo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js');

var jqueryCdn = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js';
var links = [{
    url: "http://google.com",
    sitename: "Google",
    jsinject: function() {
      var log = document.querySelectorAll('title')[0].innerText;
      console.log(log);
    }
  },
  ...
];

var sizes = [{
    device: "desktop",
    userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36",
    width: 1440,
    height: 1080
  },
  ...

];

/*
 * This function wraps WebPage.evaluate, and offers the possibility to pass
 * parameters into the webpage function. The PhantomJS issue is here:
 *
 */
var evaluate = function(page, func) {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 2);
  var fn = "function() { return (" + func.toString() + ").apply(this, " + JSON.stringify(args) + ");}";
  return page.evaluate(fn);
};

var adjustPageSettings = function(page, size) {
  page.set(
    'viewportSize', {
      width: size.width,
      height: size.height
    }
  );
  $.config.userAgent = size.userAgent;
  return page;
};

$.getPage(function(page) {
  /**
   * snaps screenshot of page and safes it
   * @param siteName
   * @param device
   * @param done
   */
  var snapShoot = function(siteName, device, done) {
    console.log('snapshooting: ' + siteName + ' for ' + device);
    page.render('screenshot' + siteName + device + '.png', done);
  };
  async.eachSeries(sizes, function(size, done) {
    async.eachSeries(links, function(link, done) {
      page = adjustPageSettings(page, size);
      page.open(link.url, function(status) {
        if (status == 'success') {
          async.series([
            function(done) {
              if (typeof link.jsinject == 'function') {
                evaluate(page, link.jsinject, '');
                done();
              } else {
                done();
              }
            },
            function(done) {
              snapShoot(link.sitename, size.device, done);
            }
          ], function() {
            done()
          });
        } else {
          console.log('couldnt load:' + link.url);
        }
      });
    }, done);
  });
});
```

But as soon as I use jQuery components as following:

```
...
$.getPage(function (page) {
    page.injectJs(jqueryCdn);
....
```

and...

```js
var links = [
    {
        url: "http://google.com",
        sitename: "Google",
        jsinject: function () {
             var log = $('title').text();
             console.log(log);
          }
},
```

I get an jQuery is not loaded error:

```
  phantom stdout: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():2
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():4
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():4
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says that jQuery was not loaded into the DOM.

The variable name `jqueryCdn` suggests that you use a remote resource (URL). [`page.injectJs()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/inject-js.html) supports only local paths. You need to use [`page.includeJs()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/include-js.html). Don't forget to use the callback otherwise it may be the case that your script is executed, but jQuery is not yet loaded into the DOM.

Comment: thanks you put me on the right track. Didnt know you had to include the js within the callback of the `page.open()` function

Comment: That's not necessarily true. I saw instances where a remote (or local; I don't remember) script was first injected and only after that the page was `open`ed.